# I do not understand how a pointer variable works when passed into a function

Tags: c++

I don't understand how a pointer variables works when passed into a function. Could you please give a brief description. Also, I don't understand how pointer return functions works.I feel like if I get a better intuition of both, I'm able to apply it when I need it.

Comment: That is way too broad to be answered in the Q&A format. You would be better off trying out an example or two from your favorite book, then formulating a question with a code sample to illustrate the points that cause misunderstanding.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time I ask a question. Thank you for the great advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### By Value

So when you pass a variable to a function it creates a *'copy'* of that variable that's used in the function meaning that if you modify the copy you won't be modifying the original but instead you'll be modifying that copy.

```
int x = 1;
std::cout << "Outside Before Function: " << x << std::endl;
function(x);
std::cout << "Outside After Function: " << x << std::endl;

void function(int x) {
    x = 100;
    std::cout << "Inside Function: " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Will print

```
Outside Before Function: 1
Inside Function: 100
Outside After Function: 1
```

#### By Reference

Where as if you pass a pointer to the function you pass the *memory address* of the variable that exists outside the function, that allows you to deference that address, and modify the variable that exists outside the function from inside without it having to be done through the return parameter. Which can allow you to return other things from the function like if it succeeded or failed.

```
int x = 1;
std::cout << "Outside Before Function: " << x << std::endl;
function(&x);
std::cout << "Outside After Function: " << x << std::endl;

void function(int * x) {
    *x = 100;
    std::cout << "Inside Function: " << *x << std::endl;
}
```

Will print

```
Outside Before Function: 1
Inside Function: 100
Outside After Function: 100
```

#### As Returns

And passing pointer returns can be useful for things like memory allocation wrappers, singleton implementations, and too many things to list or that I can even think of at the moment.

Malloc Wrapper Example

```
void * mallocWrapper(size_t size) {
    void * ret = malloc(size);
    if (malloc == nullptr) {
        exit(1);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.

Comment: Glad to help, was just as confused when I started programming :)

Comment: @Pierre It isn't very clear here, but note that pointers are also passed by value, like everything else in C++ except for references. "pass by reference" in C++ usually means passing C++ references, not pointers.

Comment: Thanks, @juanchopanza that's a very important thing to understand.

Comment: Thanks @juanchopanza, I will.